# Tkinter OptionMenu add a command to multiple OptionMenus

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter, closures, optionmenu

Basically I have a series of OptionMenus that are created in a loop, but is currently empty:

```
option_menu = []
for ii in range(jj):
    option_menu.append([])  
    for ll in range(kk):   
        option_menu[ii].append(OptionMenu(frame,tkinter_text_var[ii][ll],''))
```

Then elsewhere I use a checkbox to set the values along the lines of:

```
for ii in range(jj):
    for ll in range(kk):   
        option_menu[ii][ll]["menu"].add_command(label = name_from_box.get(), command = lambda: tkinter_text_var[ii][ll].set(name_from_box.get()))
```

This works to populate all of the OptionMenus properly, but when I select a value in any of the OptionMenus, it only sets option_menu[jj][kk] (i.e. that last one made).

So what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a *very* common question involving closures.  Look at the following example:

```
alist = [lambda : x for x in range(10) ]
print (alist[2]()) #9
print (alist[4]()) #9
```

The'll all be 9.  Why?  Because each lambda function refers to the variable `x`.  `x` gets changed at every iteration through the loop, but they all still refer to *the same object*.

One way around this is to use a default argument.  Default arguments are evaluated when the function is created, not when it is called.

```
alist = [lambda y=x: y for x in range(10) ]
print (alist[2]()) #2
print (alist[4]()) #4
```

(another way to do the same thing involves `functools.partial` which you'll see sometimes ...)

I often like to say -- "take care with closures".  They can be a little tricky.

Comment: What you say is true, but I think the answer will be confusing for someone who doesn't understand closures or lambda.

Comment: @BryanOakley -- I think that this aspect of closures is difficult to grasp for anyone.  I tried to make it clear that the x in the first example gets shared amongst all the `lambda`s whereas in the second example it isn't.  I don't know how else to say it.  If you have any suggestions for making it easier to understand I'm happy to edit (or upvote if you post a better answer ;-).

Comment: It should probably be mentioned that what is between lambda and : is similar to what is in parenthesis in function definitions. That is, it is bindings to variables that are only valid for this call to the function. The problem with the first block of code is that it just assume there is an x somewhere that it can see and that will of course "always" be the same.

Comment: So, for a dumbies understanding, this is similar to how, if you do, say `X = [1]`, `Y = X`, `X[0] = 9` then the value of `Y[0]` will also change to `9`?

Comment: @DavidDuncan -- yes, I suppose so.  In that case, `X[0]` and `Y[0]` also reference the same object.