# How to get each loop number in tkMessageBox?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I'm playing with Tkinter and just realized that I can't get the proper number of each loop.

Here's my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox as msg

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.summon()

    def summon(self):
        [tk.Button(text="Button "+str(x), width=25, command=(lambda: msg.askquestion("X!","Y"+str(x)+"?"))).grid(padx=10, pady=10) for x in range(16)]

app = App()
app.master.title("Ericson Willians")
app.mainloop()
```

As you can see, inside the summon method, I create 16 buttons. Each button gets its name-number through iteration, and the same should apply to the message box. Nevertheless, instead, all buttons give me a messagebox with the last index: 15. Why I can't get the respective number on the messagebox? Why the process is somehow differently applied to the messagebox?

Comment: I doubt that is the most canonical duplicate of this question (it's been asked many times before).  That was just one that I happened to find in a quick search of my previous answers where I knew I could find a dupe...

Comment: And here it is again:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11801232/748858 and it's listed as a FAQ on [sopython](http://sopython.com/wiki/common-questions#lambda-last-variable) -- Not that I expected you to find any of these mind you -- It's a FAQ because it's a tough one to search for unless you know _exactly_ what you're looking for ...

Comment: `command=lambda n=x: msg.askquestion("X!","Y"+str(n)+"?")`