# Changing one OptionMenu changes the second one

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, tkinter.optionmenu

In my code below I have two option menus which are populated with the same list. In the final application the list is generated by importing a .csv file.

The user should be able to select two entries from the list.

Now the problem is, that changing the first option menu, will change instead the second one.
The second one, however, works as expected.

I guess the function `update_file_list_selection()` and `lambda` function is implemented badly.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class File_Selection():
    def __init__(self, frame, text):
        self.frame = frame
        self.text = text

        self.label_file = tk.Label(self.frame, text=text)
        self.label_file.pack()

        self.variable_file = tk.StringVar(self.frame)
        self.option_list = ["no file loaded"]
        self.variable_file.set(self.option_list[0])
        self.optionmenu_file = tk.OptionMenu(self.frame, self.variable_file,
                                             *self.option_list)
        self.optionmenu_file.pack()


class View:
    def __init__(self, view, update_list):

        self.view = view
        self.view.title("Test")
        self.view.geometry("320x240")
        self.view.resizable(False, False)

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.view)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Update", command=update_list)
        self.button.pack()

        self.file_one = File_Selection(self.frame, "File 1")
        self.file_two = File_Selection(self.frame, "File 2")


class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.view = View(self.root, lambda: self.update_file_list_selection())

        self.files = ["File 1", "File 2", "File 3", "File 4"]

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update_file_list_selection(self):

        self.active_file_selection = [self.view.file_one, self.view.file_two]

        for file_selection in self.active_file_selection:

            self.menu = file_selection.optionmenu_file["menu"]
            self.menu.delete(0, "end")

            for x in self.files:
                file_selection.option_list.append(x)
                self.menu.add_command(label=x,
                        command=lambda value=x: file_selection.variable_file.set(value))

            file_selection.variable_file.set(self.files[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Controller()
    c.run()
```

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear from your description and your code what you're trying to accomplish as well as exactly how to run the code to reproduce the program.

Comment: The implemented button is only to load the list into the OptionMenu. 
After this, each OptionMenu should hold the same data. 
In the final application the entries are paths to files which hold data.
The user can now choose from the list which entry he is interested in. 
For example: he want to compare "File 1" and "File 4", therefore he select "File 1" in OptionMenu 1 and "File 4" in OptionMenu 2.
But, with my code above, if I select "File 1" in OptionMenu 1, the entry in OptionMenu 2 changes.

Comment: I think this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801121/python-tkinter-optionmenu-add-a-command-to-multiple-optionmenus could be the answer, but to be honest, I'm not sure, how to implement the solution on my code.

Comment: Yes, considered that possibility, but it looks to me like you're doing things right with respect to that the issue in that question. I still don't understand the relationship you want to have between the two `OptionMenu`s.

Comment: Actually, there should be no "relationship" between both OptionMenu's. I want to select a file individually for each OptionMenu.
But when selecting a file in OptionMenu 1 the lambda function gets triggered and changes the OptionMenu 2, not OptionMenu 1. Please let me know, if I could clarify the issue.

Comment: Because of the `self.active_file_selection = [self.view.file_one, self.view.file_two]` in the `update_file_list_selection()` method, you're essentially updating both of them with the same data.

Comment: Yes this is correct, but when changing OptionMenu 1, the change occur on OptionMenu 2, not on OptionMenu 1.
Both OptionMenus have to show the same data (["File 1", "File 2", "File 3", "File 4"]), but I want to select on each OptionMenu a different entry.

Comment: I could not reproduce that problem about changes of OptionMenu 1 occurring on #2.

Comment: Really? Because when I select "File 4" in OptionMenu 1, OptionMenu 2 will display "File 4", OptionMenu 1 has still "File 1"

Comment: Finally, a clear explanation of how to reproduce the problem. I'll look into it.

Comment: At least part of the problem is because you're confusing an [`OptionMenu`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/optionmenu.html) with a [`Menu`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/menu.html). The former has no `add_command()` method that I know of.

Comment: @martineau: _"... you're confusing an OptionMenu with a Menu"_ - that's not quite correct. an `OptionMenu` is just a `MenuButton` and a `Menu`, combined with a custom callback. The OP is calling `add_command()` on the `Menu` associated with the `OptionMenu`.

Comment: @Bryan: Thanks, obviously I didn't know that. Sigh, yet another poorly document tkinter "feature"…

Comment: @Bryan: After reading some of tkinter's source code I now understand how the OP managed to get access to the undocumented private `__menu` attribute `OptionMenu` widgets have in order to call its `add_command()` method. I had no idea they were hacking the widget like that — which seems surprising for someone who apparently didn't know about the common `lambda` values in `for` loops issue.

Comment: @martineau: the `OptionMenu` has always been a bit of an odd bird. Even in the tcl/tk world it's not a true widget, it's just a helper function that creates a standard menu and menubutton widget. In the tcl/tk version, `tk_optionMenu` returns the menu rather than the menu button, so it's kind-of expected to be able to tweak the menu. The tcl/tk version doesn't support the `command` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess the function update_file_list_selection() and lambda function is implemented badly.

That is a correct guess.

The reason is a common problem with using `lambda` - when you do `command=lambda value=x: file_selection.variable_file.set(value)`, the value of `file_selection` won't be the value from the loop, it will end up being the value of the final time that variable was set. You can solve this by binding the value to the `lambda` as a default argument:

```
self.menu.add_command(label=x, command=lambda value=x, fs=file_selection: fs.variable_file.set(value))
```

The above will make sure that inside the `lambda` body, `fs` will be set to the value of `file_selection` at the time the menu item is made rather than the value at the time the item is selected.

You'll still end up with `OptionMenu` items that don't behave exactly the same as normal `OptionMenu` items, but in this specific example that doesn't seem to matter since you don't have a `command` associated with the `OptionMenu` as a whole.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for. It seems I need to learn more about lambda functions....

Comment: Bryan: There is a command associated with each item (the one you fixed).

Comment: @martineau: right, but there isn't a command associated with the `OptionMenu` as a whole. But you're right that the way I phrased the answer is incorrect. I'll fix it.

Comment: Makes more sense now. I didn't even know that `OptionMenu`s supported a `command=` option until I recently stumbled across the fact doing some research on them.